# How to format rows of secound column concidering rows of first column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to format rows of secound column considering rows of first column.

Description::-

I have One column say column A in excel with 8 rows.

data is present in some rows and blank for some rows.
eg

```
1st row tiger
2nd row lion
3rd row (blank no data present)
4th row (blank no data present)
5th row cow
6th row (blank no data present)
7th row cat
8th row mouse.
```

Now my secound column say B in excel contains data in 85 rows consecutivly.
eg

```
1st row 1
2nd row 1
3rd row 3
4th row 4
5th row 10
```

Now i want to arrange the 2nd column according to the 1st column.

like below:

```
column A                            Column B
1st row tiger                       1
2nd row lion                        1
3rd row (blank no data present)
4th row (blank no data present)
5th row cow                         3
6th row (blank no data present)
7th row cat                         4
8th row mouse.                      10
```

Since I have huge volume of data, I need a formula to do that.

Please suggest for the same.

Comment: you gave nice examples, but however, I do not understand how the _cow_ knows it has to align with _3_ or the _tiger_ with _1_ from column B, and wich _1_ from column B?! You see, to help you with this, it is essential to know on which basis you are able to arrange this data, as you did.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the blank rows (use Filter) and paste Column B next to Column A.

You can insert rows by keeping track of row numbers - when you are done, simply take the blank rows from the original file (use Filter) and paste them under your filtered file, and sort by column index.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a few formulas:

Starting with this:
[image: Starting Sheet]

Then adding these formulas:

[image: Formulas]

`IN B2 - =IF(A2<>"",VLOOKUP(COUNTA(A$2:A2),$D$2:$E$6,2,0),"")`

`IN D3 - =D2+1`

This gives:

[image: Result]